# K8s service unreachable via master IP

Tags: networking, kubernetes, service, containers

I am learning kubernetes and currently am trying to deploy the demo hello-world container and expose it as a service (type NodePort). I have one master and one worker connected to the cluster. Using weavenet as the CNI.

I have been following the official k8s docs for [exposing it as a service.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/)

I have one replica running through deployment with it exposed as a service.

Here is the `kubectle get all` output:

```sh
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-world-f9b447754-fthwg   1/1     Running   0          2d7h

NAME                  TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/hello-world   NodePort   10.96.217.234   <none>        8080:31097/TCP   2d7h

NAME                          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/hello-world   1/1     1            1           2d7h

NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/hello-world-f9b447754   1         1         1       2d7h
```

While I am able to curl directly to `<worker IP>:<NodePort>` and get the response, I am unable to curl to the service via the `<master IP>:<NodePort>`. I am getting the error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to <master-IP> port 31097: No route to host` after a couple seconds of delay.
Any other port or via the Cluster IP gets me the error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.96.217.234 port 31097: Connection refused`

**QUESTION:**

> What am I missing here? The service should be accessible via the master IP and NodePort outside of the cluster right?
>
> kube-proxy is running on both nodes and the apiserver seems to run fine. Someone mentioned I might need to change the YAML file corresponding to the apiserver although I am not sure how to or what to regarding that.
>
> I need the service to be reachable via the master IP and exposed port. What part of the cluster config should I look at to get this working. I am new and want to learn the working of kubernetes and everything related to containers.

---

> PS

I am trying the curl command within the master node and via my PC's browser. Never works. Same works fine for worker-IP.

I am doing this inside a corporate network that uses proxies but have set no_proxy for the master and worker IPs.

Also here are all of the running pods:

```sh
NAMESPACE     NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-hhf7x              1/1     Running   0          2d10h
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-z5vx5              1/1     Running   0          2d10h
kube-system   etcd-master-node                      1/1     Running   0          2d10h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master-node            1/1     Running   0          2d10h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master-node   1/1     Running   3          2d10h
kube-system   kube-proxy-9m9gk                      1/1     Running   0          2d9h
kube-system   kube-proxy-nttqg                      1/1     Running   0          2d10h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master-node            1/1     Running   3          2d10h
kube-system   weave-net-6qlt8                       2/2     Running   1          2d10h
kube-system   weave-net-fk9nc                       2/2     Running   0          2d9h
production    hello-world-f9b447754-fthwg           1/1     Running   0          2d8h
```

Comment: Did you join the master and worker node?

Comment: I think this is network plugin issue.
https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/799

Comment: yes I have. a master and a worker.

Comment: @SachinArote Is this applicable for Weavenet too? Also even ping to neither teh master nor the worker IP returns anything. But the curl to wokerIp is still wokring.

Comment: the issue seems to be solved by changing the default cluster dns IP. followed [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1056#issuecomment-417579533). Will check if the cluster functions properly with actual services to mark this solved.

Comment: @BharathYes please provide an answer if your issue was solved.

Comment: @DawidKruk I have linked to the page I followed. It solved the issue for me but I am yet to understand what caused the issue or why this was a solution. Unless I don't understand I can't explain an answer. If someone else could explain this from the link or otherwise I am more than happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @BharathYes How was your Kubernetes cluster created?

Comment: @Dawid using kubeadm init. Didn't use any parameters regarding IP ranges like most articles. I used weavenet so wasn't sure which range to use.

Comment: I think it will be hard to pinpoint exact issue if it's resolved now.  What is your Kubernetes and weavenet version?